# get table names from DB and parse it to JCombobox and then when a tablename is select it should display the table info in the JTable

Tags: java, sqlite

I need help with retrieving tableNames from my database and then parse it to JCombobox and the when the tableName is click the sql statement will be performed and then display the table in the JTable.

My problem is how to code the selectedItem so that it will execute the query and display IT on the JTable

Here is my gui.java file

```
 package Assignment3.Live;

 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
 import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
 import java.sql.ResultSet;
 import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
 import java.sql.SQLException;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Vector;

 import javax.swing.*;
  import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
 import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
 import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
 import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
  import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
 import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;
 import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

   ;

   /**
     * @author jmickey
   * 
   */
   public class GUI extends JFrame {

// Variables
 public Main main;
  DBCon db;
 MakeTable make;

  private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   private JPanel pNorth, pChooser, pdp, pRC, pSCR, pTab, pSouth, pBtn;

  public ResultSet rseTo = null;// result set
   public PreparedStatement pst = null;
   private ResultSetMetaData meta = null;

 String tableNamesnow = "";
  private JMenuBar jMenuBar;
  private JMenu file, help;

private JComboBox<String> jcmb = new JComboBox<String>();
 ComboBoxModel<?> giveMeTableName = (ComboBoxModel<?>) jcmb
    .getSelectedItem();
 private JTable jT = new JTable();

private JTextArea text;
private JButton search, clear, displayRow, deletRow, addRow, query, save,
    restore;
private JCheckBox rowS = new JCheckBox("Select by Rows", true);
private JCheckBox colS = new JCheckBox("Selcet by Column", false);

     /*
   * private String[] columnNames = {}; private Object [][] rowData = {};
   */

  public GUI() throws SQLException {
GUInterface();
getTableNames();
arrayOfTable();
}

   public void GUInterface() {// constructor
// Menubar
setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 10));
jcmb.setSelectedItem("");
jMenuBar = new JMenuBar();
file = new JMenu("File");
file.add(new JMenuItem("Start"));
file.add(new JMenuItem("Exit"));
help = new JMenu("Help");
help.add(new JMenuItem("Help"));
jMenuBar.add(file);
jMenuBar.add(help);

// Button
save = new JButton("Save");
clear = new JButton("Clear");
restore = new JButton("Restore");

displayRow = new JButton("Display Row");
deletRow = new JButton("Delet Row");
addRow = new JButton("Add New Row");
query = new JButton("QUERY");

// choose table panel = 1
pChooser = new JPanel();
pChooser.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 0));
pChooser.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Tables"));
pChooser.add(new JLabel("Select a table: "), BorderLayout.WEST);
pChooser.add(jcmb, BorderLayout.CENTER);

// Row/Column selection Panel = 2
pRC = new JPanel();
pRC.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
pRC.add(rowS);
pRC.add(colS);

// noth panel holds (pChooser & pRC)
pNorth = new JPanel();
pNorth.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
pNorth.add(pChooser);
pNorth.add(pRC);

// JTable panel
pTab = new JPanel();
pTab.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
pTab.add(jT);
pTab.add(new JScrollPane(jT));

// display holds (pNorth & pTab)
pdp = new JPanel();
pdp.setLayout(new BorderLayout(2, 1));
pdp.add(pNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
pdp.add(pTab, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

// Save, Clear or restore Panel
pSCR = new JPanel();
pSCR.add(save);
pSCR.add(clear);
pSCR.add(restore);

// Button selection panel
pBtn = new JPanel();
pBtn.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
pBtn.add(displayRow);
pBtn.add(addRow);
pBtn.add(query);
pBtn.add(deletRow);

// South panel (pSCR & pBtn)
pSouth = new JPanel();
pSouth.setLayout(new BorderLayout(2, 1));
pSouth.add(pBtn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
pSouth.add(pSCR, BorderLayout.CENTER);

// Table info
jT.setAutoResizeMode(jT.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
jT.setGridColor(Color.BLUE);
jT.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
jT.setSelectionBackground(Color.BLUE);
jT.setSelectionForeground(Color.WHITE);
jT.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);

/*
 * Task 1. change action to diplay row = create the 2.delete row
 * 3.insert row
 */

frame.setJMenuBar(jMenuBar);
frame.add(pdp, BorderLayout.NORTH);
frame.add(pSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

frame.setTitle("Walters SPJ Directory");
frame.setResizable(true);
frame.setSize(465, 648);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);

// display rows
displayRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // when the search button is clicked
        if (e.getSource() == displayRow) {
            jcmb.setSelectedItem(giveMeTableName);
            for (int i = 0; i < jcmb.getSelectedIndex(); i++)
                displayS();
        }
    }

});

// Checkbos ActionListener
rowS.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        jT.setRowSelectionAllowed(rowS.isSelected());
    }
});
colS.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        jT.setRowSelectionAllowed(colS.isSelected());
    }
});

// Clear ActionListener
clear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TableModel myData = DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rseTo);
        jT.tableChanged(null);
    }
});

    }

     // get tableNames
      public void getTableNames() throws SQLException {
        rseTo = null;
  java.sql.DatabaseMetaData meta = DBCon.con.getMetaData();
   rseTo = meta.getTables(null, null, "%", new String[] { "TABLE" });

    while (rseTo.next()) {
    String nameOfTables = rseTo.getString(3);
    String tableCatalog = rseTo.getString(1);
    String tableSchema = rseTo.getString(2);

    System.out.printf("%s - %s - %s%n", tableCatalog, tableSchema,
            nameOfTables);
}

db.stm.close();
```

}

```
         // get table name to JCombobox
           public void arrayOfTable() throws SQLException {
            rseTo = db.con.getMetaData().getTables(null, null, "%",
        new String[] { "TABLE" });

           while (rseTo.next()) {
    String giveMeTableName = (rseTo.getString(3));

    jcmb.addItem(giveMeTableName);

    System.out.println(giveMeTableName);
            }

jcmb.setBounds(130, 30, 190, 30);
jcmb.setEditable(false);
jcmb.getSelectedIndex();

return;

 }

          /*
          * Table selection method
          */
          public void displayS() {
        try {
    String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " + giveMeTableName;
    pst = DBCon.con.prepareStatement(sql);
    rseTo = pst.executeQuery();
    TableModel myData = DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rseTo);
    jT.setModel(myData);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        }
      }

     public void displayP() {
        try {
    String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM P";
    pst = DBCon.con.prepareStatement(sql);
    rseTo = pst.executeQuery();
    jT.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rseTo));
} catch (Exception ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
}

     }

         public void displayJ() {
            try {
    String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " + make.tableName;
    pst = DBCon.con.prepareStatement(sql);
    rseTo = pst.executeQuery();
    jT.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rseTo));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
   }

       }

          public void displaySPJ() {
        try {
    String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM SPJ";
        pst = DBCon.con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rseTo = pst.executeQuery();
        jT.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rseTo));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        }

                }

             }
```

Comment: Are you required to use the .txt file as is, or could you reformat it, or convert it into a series of SQL statements?

Comment: i must use it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

For tasks like this, you need to be aware that you're developing a new (simple) programming language. This means the input is no longer free form but has to obey certain rules. For example:

```
Table name: S
...
Table name: 

P
```

is bad. The people editing the file should stick to one way to specify the table name; otherwise your parser will quickly get complex.

As a general guideline for tasks like this:

1. Read the input line by line.
2. Ignore empty lines
3. Trim lines to get rid of excessive whitespace
4. Use patterns like `Table name:` together with `line.startsWith()` to find out what the next "block" of your language means.
5. Read the values of each block and process then. `line.split("\\s", -1)` is your friend to split the input into words.

Getting it right will become easier when you create a few simple test cases and use unit tests to make sure your parser builds the correct data structures in memory.

Comment: please Aaron, I can you not show me how to do it cos am a novice, I just start Java programming and this is a school assignment, must hand it in tomorrow

Comment: I showed you how to do it. This is a Q&A site, not a "we write code for you" site.

Comment: Hi Everyone, please I need help in solving this Assignment and I failed the first submission date and now I have to make the re submission. However, this is how far I have been able to write the code.

Comment: Well, that looks promising. What are you missing?

Comment: now i need to be able to use pattern and then split it, how do i go about that

Comment: Why don't you use `content.contains("Table name:")`? Also, you should not read all the lines into a single string; it will just make things more complex.

Comment: u mean i should use while(file.hasNext) rather?

Comment: No, I mean you shouldn't use `content += ...`. Read the file line by line and process each line. Start with a simple case. Write some code. See how it behaves. Expand it.

Comment: like this while (file.hasNextLine()) {
      content += file.nextLine().trim() + "\n";

Comment: I'm sorry but I have the feeling that you're overwhelmed by the task. If this is the case, then this site isn't for you. We expect you to have a minimal understanding of what you want to achieve and the technology involved. What you seem to need is 1:1 coaching, that can't be done with 500 character comments.

Comment: do you know where I can get 1:1 coaching?

Comment: Why don't you ask around at your school/college?

Comment: I have but there is none willing to give me that, why is it that difficult to understand this programming? I really want to learn it

Comment: Software development means: 1. Know your tools. 2. Know how to split big task into many small tasks. 3. Play around. The last points means you really need to try things. Write code, run it, see how it breaks. Try different approaches.

Comment: I am in my first month in SEM and I have not been able to understand much, I am sorry if I border you but I am disturbed myself and I want to know what am doing but am kind off displaced. But thanks a lot for ur help

Comment: The life of a software developer is a lot like this. You have to ask yourself what stops you from making progress. Are you missing some information? Or are you unhappy / unwilling to spend the effort? The code above looks like you understood the basics. That's good. Now go on. Write the next line of code. It's okay when it doesn't work. I have 120+K points here and I throw away half of all the code that I write because it's broken in one way or the other. Accept it. It's normal.

Comment: now i did some coding can you check and tell me what's next. Thanks. Please don't get upset I am a beginner.

Comment: The next step is to do something useful with `contentInFile`